# import python modules on matlab using pyrunfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, import, package

I have a python script that depends on imported packages, as shown:

```
#script stored as get_command_Voltage.py

import pyabf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#load data
def get_command_V(filepath):
    abfdata = pyabf.ABF(filepath)
    return abfdata


commandv = get_command_V(filepath1)
```

and I'd like to store the python output, commandv, in the variable commandV in matlab.

I wrote the following code on Matlab:

```
pyabf = py.importlib.import_module('pyabf');

filepath_this = "..." %full file path

commandV = pyrunfile("get_command_Voltage.py","commandv",filepath1 = filepath_this)
```

but it gives me

> ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'pyabf'

```
Warning: Unable to load Python object. Saving (serializing) Python objects into a MAT-file is not supported. 
> In vclampanal (line 25) 
Error using <frozen importlib>_find_and_load_unlocked (line 1140)
Python Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyabf'

Error in <frozen importlib>_find_and_load (line 1176)

Error in <frozen importlib>_gcd_import (line 1204)

Error in __init__>import_module (line 126)
```

I'm just wondering how I could resolve this issue and run python scripts that depend on imports.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Your usage of `pyrunfile` [looks correct](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyrunfile.html) but I don't think your `pyabf = ...` line is what you want (apart from anything else, you don't do anything with your MATLAB object `pyabf`). Are you sure that the `pyabf` package is actually installed for the Python interpreter that MATLAB is using, i.e. the one that's shown if you type `pyenv` in the console? Does that match what Python returns for `sys.executable`?

Comment: @nekomatic Thank you so much for your reply!  The python interpreter shown from pyenv is the same as the one for sys.executable. But Pyabf has the path "/Users/sayakaminegishi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyabf/__init__.py" while pyenv shows version 3.11 with executable at "/usr/local/bin/python3". Do you think this is contributing to the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB can only access Python packages installed in the Python environment specified by pyenv. If MATLAB is pointing to a different Python installation, it won't be able to load or recognize packages installed in another environment (like your Anaconda environment).

Step 1. Open a terminal or Anaconda Prompt.

Step 2. Activate the Anaconda environment where pyabf is installed (if you use a specific environment, otherwise skip this step).

Step 3. Run

> which python

on macOS/Linux or

> where python

on Windows to find the path to the Python executable in the active environment.

Step 4. Copy the path to the Python executable.
It should be something like

> /Users/sayakaminegishi/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

(for macOS/Linux) or a similar path on Windows.

Step 5. Open MATLAB and use the pyenv command to set the Python executable path to the one you found in the previous step.

> pyenv('Version', '/Users/sayakaminegishi/opt/anaconda3/bin/python');

Step 6. Run pyenv again in MATLAB to verify that it's now using the correct Python version and path.